# GA4 - set up conversions

Tags: google-analytics-4

Hi Everyone I'm trying to complete the migration to GA4, I already did for another site I have and I was able to import from universal analytics. For this site it says "Universal Analytics Missing permission". I'm an admin for both universal analytics and for the G4 property. I have admin permissions for direct Roles and effective roles. I don't know what else to do. Thanks in advance!

[image]